# Image mapping tools to allow for easy and smooth coordinate drawings

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap, imagemapster

I'm using [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) to help add effects to my image maps. They have an example of a skeleton with beautifully outlined/mapped body parts:

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/joints/SkeletonJointExample.html

[image]

I've found some [tools](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/) to help me map coordinates, but it's not easy at all to get smooth outline maps like above... instead I end up with clunky shapes, like such:

[image]

Is there an easier way to map coordinates, or do I have to get a larger picture and meticulously map the coordinates by drawing polyshapes?

Answer (score 0):

give mapedit (shareware, $15) a try. http://www.boutell.com/mapedit/ it has a "magic wand" tool beside standard tools like polygon